# Orgmode latex export of figures: how to apply placement string?

Tags: org-export

In the past, I have exported org-mode source code blocks into LaTeX floating environments, without any problems.

At some point (I have no idea when), this behavior has changed for me.

1. The org manual says `:float t` is the default if the source block has a caption, but I get no `\begin{figure}` in the exported output.

   ```
   #+name: a
   #+caption: abc
   #+BEGIN_SRC SuperCollider -i
   abc.play;
   #+END_SRC
   ```

   -->

   ```
   \lstset{language=SuperCollider,label=a,caption={abc},captionpos=b,numbers=none}
   \begin{lstlisting}
   abc.play;
   \end{lstlisting}
   ```
2. Source code blocks aren't processing `#+ATTR_LATEX`, whether it comes before the name and caption or immediately before `#+BEGIN_SRC`.
3. If I try to force a float using `#+BEGIN_FIGURE`, I can't find a way to attach a placement string. `#+ATTR_LATEX` appears to be ignored.

Tried with org-mode v8.3.5.

[1] http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html#LaTeX-specific-attributes

Comment: I got #3 working: `#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [th]`. #1 and #2, still no idea.

Comment: For me, using org-mode 8.3.4, `#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [th]` works for #3, although I put this just above the `#RESULT` header created when running the source block (using `C-c C-c`) and I didn't add any manual `#+BEGIN_FIGURE`.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following attribute in org file and it works with org-mode v8.2.10.

There are many bugs or incompatible updates in org-mode v8.3.5, so I suggest you to try it with v8.2.10.

```
#+CAPTION: example
#+LABEL: fig:example-fig
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H]
[[file:example.png]]
```

Comment: That is for an image link. My question is about source code blocks. Also, I had originally been using 8.2-something when I saw the problem. I updated, thinking maybe it had been fixed, but the behavior didn't change.